Why does the LC oscillator work according to the scheme with a common base?
I study HF oscillators and i stuck. I put build the following circuit:

The waveform:

A question arises. Why does this work at all, because the input resistance of the circuit is extremely low. In this scheme input impedance:
$$
R_{in} = r_e = \frac{\varphi_t}{I_{e0}} \approx \frac{25mV}{(5-0.7)/2.2k}  = 13 Ohm! 
$$
It immediately seems that with such a low input resistance, the loop gain is almost guaranteed to be less than zero and oscillations will not occur. On the other hand, even if we assume that fluctuations will still occur, then C4 will in any case be shunted through the BE transition to earth, which should lead to a change in the generation frequency, but this also does not happen. Estimated frequency:
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt(L (C1||C2))} = 100.6 MHz
$$
In fact, the measured frequency almost completely coincides with the calculations.
In addition, if you slightly transform the circuit (if the circuit is completely included in the collector circuit, replacing C_1 and C_4 with a capacitor of their equivalent capacity in series and supply the output to the input through a separating capacitor), then vibrations cease to be generated. In theory, as it should be:

In addition, if an emitter repeater is added to the second converted circuit in the simulator in order to increase the input resistance, then fluctuations occur, as they should.
What is so magical about turning on the midpoint of the capacitors?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colpitts_oscillator

Your circuit uses the emitter directly as an input but consider this scenario; if you had a 1 kΩ collector resistor and a 1 kΩ resistor in series with the emitter to a signal source (AC coupled), the gain would be unity. If you lower the emitter signal resistor to 100 Ω, the gain would be ten. If you lowered the emitter signal resistor to 10 Ω, the gain would be 100.
Do you now see that the internal emitter resistance is irrelevant because the lower it is, the more it attenuates the input signal but, the lower it is the more the gain is increased = no difference.

In addition, if an emitter repeater is added to the second converted
circuit in the simulator in order to increase the input resistance,
then fluctuations occur, as they should.
What is so magical about turning on the midpoint of the capacitors?

Your additional questions seems to not make any sense or reads so badly that I can't make any sense of it. Please fix it and I'll attempt to answer.

Thanks for answer. Compare the first two circuits - the second one does not have a series connection of capacitors. Apparently, this somehow reduces the equivalent resistance of the transistor, because if you add an emitter folower, then the second circuit starts working.

I'm sorry @СтаниславТимошко but I've rolled your question back to how it was originally presented because, your more recent amendments make my answer appear incorrect. If you are going to amend your question with the new circuit and corrected then you should do so as a clear an obvious edit at the end of the question. In other words, if you have received an answer that causes you to rethink your question then you need to amend your question with respect to that answer.


What is so magical about turning on the midpoint of the capacitors?

I am interpreting this statement as, "choosing to divide the resonating capacitor into two equal parts"
The estimation of oscillating frequency as \$\omega={{1}\over{\sqrt{L\times C_1||C_4}}}\$ is crude. C1 has more influence over resonating frequency than C4. This is true because a high proportion of collector voltage appears across C1, much less across C4. This is partly due to the very low emitter impedance, and partly due to the transistor's emitter-to-base capacitance.
For the two LT-spice-simulated circuits below, load resistor for Q1 (1.3kohm) differs from load resistor for Q2 (1.1kohm) so that collector voltage and transistor collector currents are similar. Note that no attempt has been made to match component nomenclature to OP's original circuit...the right-most circuit is most similar to OP's.

Q1 oscillating frequency is 83.4 MHz
Q2 oscillating frequency is 81.8 MHz


 The two feedback capacitors are often chosen to provide an impedance match between the low emitter impedance of the common-base transistor up to the high collector impedance. This impedance match tends to make the collector-to-emitter capacitor smaller than emitter-to-gnd capacitor when done optimally.

Thank you for the response! It turns out that the two feedback capacitors do help match the impedances. How does this happen and what makes it possible?

About half-way through this long page: https://www.qsl.net/va3iul/Impedance_Matching/Impedance_Matching.pdf Iulian shows the Tapped Capacitive Impedance Transformer equations
